SELECT doing different operations on multiple columns with structured data
I’m working with a Snowflake table where each row contains structured data in two columns. Here’s an example of the table with 3 rows:
| id |  data_1             |   data_2          |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 2024-01-01, 1       | 2023-02-01, 2     |
|    | 2024-01-02, 2       | 2023-02-02, 2     |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 2  | 2024-02-03, 3       | 2023-02-01, 20    |
|    | 2024-02-02, 4       | 2023-02-02, 20    |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 3  | 2024-03-01, 5       | 2023-02-01, 30    |
|    | 2024-03-02, 6       | 2023-02-02, 30    |
|----------------------------------------------|

Conceptually, in each row, columns data_1 and data_2 contain an array of structured data where each element has a date and an integer value associated with it.
I want to query this table and obtain the following results:

For data_1: the value associated with the latest date.
For data_2: the sum of all values.

Note: I need the date in data_2 for other operations.
Desired result of the query:
| id | data_1 | data_2 |
|----------------------|
| 1  | 2      | 4      |
|----------------------|
| 2  | 3      | 40     |
|----------------------|
| 3  | 6      | 60     |
|----------------------|

Questions:

Which Snowflake data types are best suited for data_1 and data_2? Ideally, I prefer a data type where I can address each sub-element using a name (something akin to data_1.date and data_1.value, so perhaps a structured object or a structured map).
How do you write the query to achieve the desired result?


Have you looked into the docs, yet?  There is an entire section for structured data types in there, but please note they are only supported on Iceberg Tables at this point.

We can do a lot with filter and transform, but we still need a reduce - so we will implement that with a JS UDF in the meantime.
with data as (
    select 1 id, [{'date':'2024-01-01', 'v':1}, {'date':'2024-01-02', 'v':2}] data_1, [{'date':'2023-02-01', 'v':2}, {'date':'2023-02-02', 'v':2}] data_2
    union all select 2 id, [{'date':'2024-02-03', 'v':3}, {'date':'2024-02-02', 'v':4}], [{'date':'2023-02-01', 'v':20}, {'date':'2023-02-02', 'v':20}] 
    union all select 3 id, [{'date':'2024-03-01', 'v':5}, {'date':'2024-03-02', 'v':6}], [{'date':'2023-02-01', 'v':30}, {'date':'2023-02-02', 'v':30}] 
)

select arrays_to_object(transform(data_1, x -> x['date']), transform(data_1, x -> x['v']))[array_max(transform(data_1, y -> y['date']))]
    , array_sum_js(transform(data_2, x -> x['v']))
from data
;


The JS UDF:

create function array_sum_js(X array)
returns float
language javascript as
$$
    return X.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
$$;


With REDUCE available both columns expressions can be much simplified. SELECT REDUCE(data_1, {'date':'0000-01-01'::DATE, 'v':NULL}, (acc, x) -> iff(x:date > acc:date, {'date':x:date, 'v':x:v}, acc)):v::INT AS data_1_newest_v       ,REDUCE(data_2, 0,  (acc, x) -> acc + x:v::INT) AS data_2_v_sum FROM data; Query and query results
